# Why is this MYSQL CASE not working?

Tags: mysql, case

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE keywords LIKE '%face food%'
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%,face food,%' THEN 1
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%face food%' THEN 2
    WHEN soundex(`keywords`) LIKE CONCAT('%',soundex('face food'), '%') THEN 3
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%,facefood,%' THEN 4
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%facefood%' THEN 5
    WHEN soundex(`keywords`) LIKE CONCAT('%',soundex('facefood'), '%') THEN 6
  END
```

Comment: _not working_ means what? Do you get an error? What output do you get? What output do you expect? Please add some sample data.

Comment: it not displays result

Comment: is this syntax is correct ?

Comment: @BhuvneshKumar check my answer

Comment: If there’s no results then it has nothing to do with the CASE since that happens after the results are retrieved

Comment: So, do you get any results without the order by? As I said: Please add some sample data

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: You have in your where statement the string comparison `LIKE '%face food%'` which means that you select only the rows containing this string in this specific format (it doesn't include the ones that contains just format 'facefood' for example). And this in turns means that most of the case structure options are completely superfluous in this example (as it can reach only cases 1 and 2 from the list with this where clause)...

Answer (score 0):

@Bhuvnesh Kumar...

just add Else statement

this is the example one....

```
SELECT 
    customerName, state, country
FROM
    customers
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN state IS NULL THEN country
    ELSE state
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed last `else` clause your query will be

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE keywords LIKE '%face food%'
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%,face food,%' THEN 1
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%face food%' THEN 2
    WHEN soundex(`keywords`) LIKE CONCAT('%',soundex('face food'), '%') THEN 3
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%,facefood,%' THEN 4
    WHEN keywords LIKE '%facefood%' THEN 5
    WHEN soundex(`keywords`) LIKE CONCAT('%',soundex('facefood'), '%') THEN 6
   Else 7
  END
```